# Why not change color when pressed?

Tags: java, android, switch-statement, tablelayout

*when you click the color should change to another* 
  but it doesnt work!
   My code:

#

```
   public class CreateActivity extends Activity {

TableLayout table;
Integer i;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
      table = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.myTable);

    Button left = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLeft);
    Button right = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonRight);
    TextView color = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);

     i=0;

    right.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        i++; //+1
        }
    });
       //COLOR
    switch(i){
    case 1: table.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED); break;
    case 2: table.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb (255, 127, 0) ); break;
    case 3: table.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW); break;
    case 4: table.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN) ; break;
    case 5: table.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb (0,191,255) ); break;
    case 6: table.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE ); break;
    case 7: table.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb (160,32,240) ); break;

    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

When the button is clicked, you're incrementing `i` - but you won't be running the switch/case statement again. If you look in the debugger you'll find that the variable value is changing, but you haven't instructed any part of the *display* to change.

You should put that common logic in a separate method which is called both from the `onCreate` method *and* the `OnClickListener`. For example:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    table = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.myTable);

    Button left = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLeft);
    Button right = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonRight);
    TextView color = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);

    i=0;

    right.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            i++;
            // Cycle round
            if (i == 8) {
               i = 1;
            }
            applyBackgroundColor();
        }
    });

    applyBackgroundColor();
}

private void applyBackgroundColor() {
    switch(i) {
        // TODO: Consider what you want to do when i is 0...
        case 1: table.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED); break;
        case 2: table.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(255, 127, 0)); break;
        case 3: table.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW); break;
        case 4: table.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN); break;
        case 5: table.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(0,191,255)); break;
        case 6: table.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE); break;
        case 7: table.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(160,32,240)); break;   
    }
}
```

There are various other things I'd change about this code, but that should at least get you over this hump.

Comment: Thank you very much!
  But I also need to change the color back

Comment: @Vlad: When? And back to what, exactly?

Comment: @Vlad: Okay, so you need to add another click handler to `left`. That's out of the scope of your original question though - and I would get the "right" button working first. After that it should be relatively easy to apply the same *kind* of code to the left button.